# Unit Test case for services method in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I want to write the test case for Service class.

My Service Class dynamic-form.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DynamicFormService {

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(private handler: HttpBackend
  ) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(handler);
  }

  async getDynamicFormData(paramName: any, data?: any): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.get(this.HostUrl + paramName).toPromise();
  }

  async getTaskByWorkflowId(paramNameWithId): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.get(this.HostUrl + paramNameWithId).toPromise();
  }

  async getAccontType(paramNameWithId): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.get(this.HostUrl + paramNameWithId).toPromise();
  }
}
```

My dynamic-form.spec.ts are as follows

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { DynamicFormServiceService } from './dynamic-form-service.service';

describe('DynamicFormServiceService', () => {
  let service: DynamicFormServiceService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(DynamicFormServiceService);
    httpMock= TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And I don't know how to begin with writing unit test cases. I tried to google some examples and tried to implement using spyOn but it giving me some error.
Any proper way to test my service methods.

Currently I Written on of my test case like

```
it('should call getAccontType', ()=>{
    const data = [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "24hrs"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "48hrs"
      }];
    service.getAccontType(`account-type`).then(res=> expect(res.length).toBeGreaterThan(0));
    const request = httpMock.expectOne(`http://localhost:8080/account-type`);
    expect(request.request.method).toBe('GET');
    request.flush(data);
    httpMock.verify();
  });
```

Comment: Please provide the code that has `spyOn` and fails, so that we can help you, otherwise stackoverflow is not a place for tutorial recommendations.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов sorry , I have currently modified my question. Instead of using spyOn I changed the implementation. Is it a good way or not. I don't have the error details which I was facing when using spyOn.

Comment: In my opinion you have wrong test name, your test is checking if `getAccountType` returns response, not if it has been called. You can post your question here   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  and i guess there will be people that will provide you with adequate feedback